# Why is the HFS Plus attributes file unusually small, for only a while, after using Time Machine to restore a Lion system?

Tags: macos, time-machine

Once after using Time Machine in Lion Recovery OS to restore a system, I noticed that the attributes B-tree was unusually small.

Initially I was worried (had Time Machine failed to backup some *thing*, or failed to backup important *metadata* relating to a *number* of files?) but before long, I was reassured:

- the attributes file grew to something like the size it was before erasure.

During the period of growth I was vaguely aware of the system being **busy at various times**. For a restored system: the business didn't surprise me, but from things like Activity Monitor I gained an impression that **not much** of the business was Spotlight-related, which sparked my curiosity. When I realised that the attributes file had grown so much, I was **very** puzzled.

Splitting and rephrasing the question:

## What types of data are written to the attributes file?

Answers to this question might give examples of types of data. From the manual page for `ls` I'm familiar with option `-@`

> Display extended attribute keys and sizes in long (-l) output.

Apple's TN1150 offers technical information, but no examples.

## Timing: is some of that data written only after documents and other files have been parsed by the System?

In a possibly related question, I wonder whether Quick Look *preview* data (maybe distinct from *thumbnail* data) is written to an attributes file:

- [For applications that do not store Quick Look information within the file, where does Lion (or a Server) store that information?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/20158/8546)

I have [fileXray](http://filexray.com/), and am prepared to use it before and after a future Time Machine restoration of a system, but with a good set of answers to this question I might not need to use it.

### Reference

Technical Note TN1150: HFS Plus Volume Format: [Attributes File](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn/tn1150.html#AttributesFile) (2004) is somewhat vague:

> … reserved for implementing named forks in the future. … An attributes
> files has a variable length key and three data record types, which
> makes it roughly as complex as the catalog file. …
>
> **IMPORTANT**:
>
> The exact organization of the attributes B-tree has not been fully
> designed. Specifically:
>
> - the structure of the keys in the attribute B-tree has not been
>   finalized and is subject to change, and
> - addition attribute's file data record types may be defined. …